# import eclipse project / makefile into cppcheck

Tags: cppcheck

I am searching for a trick how to get a config for cppcheck from an existing (huge) Eclipse-Project and or the generated Makefile(s)

Any Ideas how to do that? Mainly List of sourcefiles, List of Includes

PS: any of the cppcheck plugins fail to install with various newer eclipse versions. So that is not an option.

Comment: Smart import for C/C++ projects has been improved in the [upcoming Eclipse 2021-12](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-12/rc1): https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn105#Build If your case is not covered, you might consider improve smart import and contribute it to Eclipse.

Comment: I do not want to import to eclipse (I droped using it ~10 years ago, only use it when forced), I want to import to cppcheck